# Laravel Conditional Clause When()

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and have encountered a problem using when() function. To start this  I do have a form consisting of 3 input fields named: name, email, and password.

```
<form method="post" action="/users">
    <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Also I have this code inside a controller file.

```
$role = $request->input('role');

        $first = User::when($role,function ($query) use ($role){
            return $query->where('username',$role);
        })->get();
```

Based on Laravel documentation this shouldn't work as no elements named 'role' in the form that I submitted and $role variable must return false. But when I loop the $first variable, It has all the records inside of Users table. So I tried correcting and put

```
$role = $request->input('name');
```

So it works perfectly when I put a name that is inside the User table. But when I type nothing at (input type='text' name='name') element and submit the form. It shows all the records inside of Users table again. I am really confused, I think it has something to do with the 'false' or 'empty' returned by the $request->input(). Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The when method will execute the given callback when the first argument given to the method evaluates to true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vishal Varshney :)

Comment: Thanks @RowelAbenio

Answer (score 0):

When `$role` is `false`, the closure is not executed, so you'll simply get this query:

```
User::get();
```

This query will just return all users.

You need to use simple `where()` in this situation:

```
User::where('username', $role)->first();
```

It will return an User object or `null` if `$role` is empty.

Comment: Ohh thank you. Now I get it. So when() method will not execute if the first parameter is false and will just continue and use get(). I thought the whole query will not work if the when() method get a false parameter. I am actually exploring what I can do with this method. Thank you very much Alexey :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `$role` variable is set then the mysql query will look like this

```
select * from `users` where `role_id` = 1
```

If `$role` isn't set like `false` then the mysql query will look like this

```
select * from `users`
```

You should edit your query for example with `if` and use different `where()`

Comment: Now I understand what will happen when when() method gets a false parameter. Thank you very much UfguFugullu

Comment: No problem - I had to try it by myself to understand this. If this solve your problem please mark this answer.